# Windows 10 Hotfix Installation Issue

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework, hotfix

I'm trying to install a particular piece of software from a manufacturers website. They have stated that it is 100% compatible with Windows 10, however I run in to this dialogue when trying to install:

[image: Error Encountered]

I've tried to install this hotfix manually but get this error:

[image: Hotfix Error]

I've also been in to the "Updates Installed" area of "Program And Features" and found that KB982638 is not listed. So I can only assume it is no longer required by Windows 10 or not compatible.

The question is, can I trick the installer in to thinking its already there, or can I find out what is blocking the install in any way? I'm not a computer wizard, or very good with the registry, so go easy if I've missed something obvious! This is really stressing me out though so any help is appreciated!

Comment: .NET 4.6 is already present on Windows 10. So any hotfix for lower versions of .NET 4.X will not install on the machine. This is installing in maintenance mode that means it is already installed and it is trying to repair the existing installation. You will need to figure out the Launch conditions i.e. the registry key that it uses to detect if .NET 4 KB is present and simulate it on your machine to get the installer going. It is best you contact the vendor with the particular screenshot as the installer needs to be fixed

Comment: To be clear, the name of the software is  called "maintenance". It definitely isn't installed already. I'll contact the vendor too. Is there an easy method to simulate a registry key?

Comment: I did not know it is called maintainence. If you know the exact registry key, you can just add it, run the installer and remove the key. But knowing the exact key can be troublesome

Answer (score 0):

I am working with this program on windows 8/10 too. The only way out is to install it on a windows 7 or lower version and transfer all files to your machine. This program is not bound to any DLL or registry so you don't need to get it from the installer.

Comment: IFM have released a Windows 10 compatible version now, so its all ok!